# Question about the mechanics of iPhone view controllers (i.e., explain why this crashes)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, xib

I am pretty new to iPhone programming, and was playing around with an app yesterday trying different scenarios with view controllers and nib files. So, I started a new app with a FirstViewController (FVC for short) and an FVC.xib.

I layed out a quick view in FVC.xib and ran the app - view displays, great.

I now wanted to have a second view I could add on top of the main view. So I went ahead and created SecondViewController.xib (SVC) but did not create the .m and .h files. I went about trying to load both these views from the same view controller, and here is where my question lies:

I created a button in FVC.xib and created an IBAction like this:

```
- (IBAction)loadSVC {
    FirstViewController *viewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    secondView = viewcontroller.view;
    [viewController release];
    [self.view addSubView:secondView];
}
```

So this works great and adds the contents of SVC.xib, but when I try and remove that view from the superview, the app crashes:

```
[secondView removeFromSuperview];
```

If I actually create a view controller for SVC, use that to instantiate my view in FVC, and move the remove code to the SVC:

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Everything works. My question - I kind of get why my first method crashes, but I was hoping someone could explain why and what goes on behind the scenes. I'm still a noob with object oriented programming, so what is actually happening in my first case where I create a new instance of FirstViewController and add its view to self.view? Why can't I release it (I assume because the original view is associated with FirstViewController, and when I create a new instance with the second xib it messes everything  up) - I'd love a more technical explanation as to what is happening...

Thanks much!!

**EDIT to add more info in response to Nick's reply below**

Nick - so your answer did clear my thinking a bit in regards to the retain count, etc... I did another test app trying to get this working from a single view controller - think, for example, that I wanted to display an Alert or Welcome message to the user (I know in a real app there are different methods to accomplish this, but this is more of a learning experience) -- so I have my main view @ MainViewController and layout my alert message in a xib called alert.xib -- so there is no logic behind the alert message, no reason for it to have a view controller that I can see, my end goal being loading/unloading this on top of my main view from the main view's view controller (or understanding why it is impossible)

I tried this using instance variables as you recommended:

In MainViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

UIViewController *secondController;
UIView *secondView;

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController {

}

@property(nonatomic, retain) UIViewController *secondController;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *secondView;

- (IBAction)loadSecond;
- (IBAction)removeSecond;

@end
```

In MainViewController.m:

```
#import "MainViewController.h"

@implementation MainViewController

@synthesize secondController, secondView;

- (IBAction)loadSecond {
secondController = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"alert" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
secondView = secondController.view;
[self.view addSubview:secondView];
}

- (IBAction)removeSecond {
//I've tried a number of things here, like [secondView removeFromSuperview];, [self.secondView removeFromSuperview];, [secondController.view removeFromSuperview];
}
- (void)dealloc {
[secondController release];
[secondView release];
[super dealloc];
}
```

So - this works to load the alert view, but the removeSecond button does nothing (I did use NSLog to verify the removeSecond method is fired) - why?

Second, and most importantly - is this even possible, or is it horrible practice? Should every nib/view I am manipulating have their own view controller? Am I wrong to think I could just make a new instance of MainViewController and use it to display and remove this no-functionality, very temporary view? (And yes, I realize I could easily create this view programatically or accomplish the end goal in many different ways which would be easier, but I'm trying to really learn this stuff and I think figuring this out will help...

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Based on your clarifications, you don't need `secondView` property or iVar. Also in your `loadSecond` instead of `secontController = bla` you need `self.secondController = bla`, otherwise you simply assign reference to the iVar instead of going through the setter.
2. Yes, it's possible to load subviews/other resources from a nib without having a dedicated controller

This is how you do it (one of the approaches):

```
UIView *result = nil;
NSArray *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyNibName" owner:owner options:nil];
for ( id o in bundle ) {
    if ( [o isKindOfClass:[UIView class]] ) {
        result = (UIView *)o;
        break;
    }
}
```

Here the result will contain the first UIView in `MyNibName`. You can use other criteria to find out whether you got the view you wanted (tags, types...)

Comment: Thanks for the additional help! I'm still a bit fuzzy on this stuff, do you have any good resources you'd recommend reading that does a good job explaining some of these concepts?

Comment: PS - one last question, can you tell me why my removeSecond method does not remove the subview? Since I haven't released anything from memory, shouldn't [secondView removeFromSuperview] remove that view? It doesn't crash, it just does nothing... I'll be using the method you posted here, but would love to know why this didn't work - thanks!

Comment: Start here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html - It's got conceptual details behind nib files as well as sample code (scroll down) for loading contents of nibs

Comment: FYI - was able to get it working using [self.view removeFromSuperview]; - thought that would remove the entire view, but it just removes the second (sub) view...

Comment: Make sure to set some distinguishable background color to self.view (yellow/red/etc), I really don't see how it's possible to call `removeFromSuperview` without it going away - maybe it just has the same color as the main window and it looks like the subview disappears? Just a guess

Comment: The subview was a diff color, smaller size (so it only partially obscured the main view) and had a button on it, so it was pretty easy to see if it disappeared...strange, but is that normal behavior? (calling removeFromSuperview would work on self.view but not on the secondView object I used in addSubview?) I have a lot to learn, thanks for the link...going through all the docs now, although I find the language a bit tough to digest.

Comment: Hm, no it's not normal. I would put a break point where you call `removeFromSuperview` and make sure that the object you call it on is not `nil` (in debugger type `po secondView`). Smth somewhere is definitely not right. In obj-c you can call any selector on a `nil` object and it will simply return 0 or `nil` without throwing any exceptions... so be aware of that - it's the only thing I can think of right now

Answer (score 3):

1. You created a view controller
2. You accessed its `view` which caused controller to create the view and call the delegates (i.e. `viewDidLoad`)
3. Controller returns the view that you asked for
4. Now you add the view as a subview which increases its retain count
5. Controller is released and it releases the view, BUT since view's retain count was increased the view is still there
6. You try to remove the view, it is unloaded and delegates are to be called (e.g. `viewDidUnload`), however that messes up since the controller who created the view is released and that piece of memory is... smth else :)

That's why the first method doesn't work.

The second method is *NOT* correct either but it works because:

1. You remove controller's view from superview but since controller itself is not released (you didn't call `[self release]` or anything like that, not saying that you should :), just an example), then the view didn't reach 0 (zero) retain count and is still there - which means its subviews aren't removed
2. The proper way to do it is to save the reference to the controller as an instance variable (usually declare a synthesized property), and release it only when you are done with the view, making sure that the view is removed from superview before hand. The default templete for a View Based App shows how view controller should be managed

Hope this helps to understand why both methods behave differently

Comment: Nick - thanks for the answer. This does help explain things, but also raises more questions for me! I'm going to post my additional comments above in the original question so I can post the code I'm using...thanks!